# The difference between Z and Kendalls Tau in Mann-Kendall

Tags: kendall-tau

In Mann-Kendall test there are 3 values, p-value, Z-value and Kendalls Tau value.
What I want to know is what the difference in concept between Z and Kendalls Tau, as I read that both of them indicate the positive or negative relation between the variable?